# Whose eyes did Uchiha Madara use during the ninja war?

Tags: naruto

I knew that Madara possesses the eyes of his brother to obtain [Eternal Mangekyō Sharingan](http://narutofanon.wikia.com/wiki/Eternal_Mangeky%C5%8D_Sharingan) but is he still using those eyes during the Fourth Ninja World War? Or has he implanted different eyes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, he is still using Izuna's eyes.

Those are the eyes with which he invoked the Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan and the Rinnegan.